# Difference between using hook useState and declare variable

Tags: typescript, hook, state

What's the difference between

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

and

```
function Example() {
  const count = 0;
```

with respect to the semantics of the count variable?

In addition to the existence of the setCount method, what are the advantages of using the useState hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason is that if you use setCount without the count from useState, the view wont know it must re-render, they both go together so it knows how to be in sync.

Every time you use setCount, it does a full render again.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function onClick() {
    setCount(count+1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={onClick}>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const count = 0;
  const [, setCount] = useState(count);

  function onClick() {
    setCount(count+1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={onClick}>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```